# How to temporarily pause a loop in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I've been developing a simon says game, but once I called the method to show the order of the buttons to be pressed, they are shown too fast. I already tried Thread.sleep(2000), Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable, 2000), but they did not work.

Here is my code:

```
public void showOrder(){
    for(Integer elem : values){
        //Pauses for 2 seconds

        //************************************HOW????????????????
        switch (elem) {
            case 2131165245:
                //buttonUp shines
                buttonUp.startAnimation(vanish);
                break;
            case 2131165246:
                //buttonLeft shines
                 buttonLeft.startAnimation(vanish);
                  break;
            case 2131165247:
                 //buttonRight shines
                  buttonRight.startAnimation(vanish);
                  break;
            case 2131165248:
                 //buttonDown shines
                 buttonDown.startAnimation(vanish);
                 break;
        }

    }

}
```

Hope someone helps me!

Comment: You should use constants from `R.id` rather than literals such as `2131165245`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution would be to make the animation durations the correct duration,

Otherwise use a method on another thread that has a sleep in it - just make sure it is not running on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Handler in a static manner. You need to first create a new instance of handler inside the activity (assuming the call for method is inside activity as OP hasn't mentioned). You can do it like this:

```
class blah extends activity{

    Handler handler=null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle xyz) {

        //initial code
        super.onCreate(xyz);
        setContentView(R.layout.content);


        //create handler
        handler = new Handler();

        //remaining code

        showOrder();

    }

    void showOrder() {
        for(Integer elem : values){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

               // content

        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

Another thing that you can do is create an asynctask and do it. For more information refer to [Worker threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) android developer's guide. Asynctasks allow you to perform task in a baground 'worker thread' which can be made to sleep without causing any ANRs and post the result on the main UI thread.

Read [Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html) on Android Developers Blog.

Happy coding! :)